# Why can't I insert data into MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.1

I try to insert those values on the persistence class
but I can't and I don't know why
I've tried a lot of things and wasted a lot of hours with any results:'(
I'm noob in JPA JSF

ENTITY CLASS

```
package testes;

import entity.Automovel;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class PersistidorDeAutomovel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.
createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
Automovel auto = new Automovel();
auto.setAnoFabricacao(2010);
auto.setModelo("Ferrari");
auto.setObservacoes("Nunca foi batido");
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(auto);
tx.commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
}
}
```

JPAUtil CLASS

```
package testes;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class JPAUtil {
private static final EntityManagerFactory emf =
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("default");
public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
return emf.createEntityManager();
}
}
```

PERSISTENCE TEST CLASS, JUST CREATED IT TO TEST IF I COULD INSERT DATA INTO THE DATABASE. I just don't understand why it isn't working

```
package testes;

import entity.Automovel;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class PersistidorDeAutomovel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.
createEntityManagerFactory("default");
EntityManager em = JPAUtil.getEntityManager();
Automovel auto = new Automovel();
auto.setAnoFabricacao(2010);
auto.setModelo("Ferrari");
auto.setObservacoes("Nunca foi batido");
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(auto);
tx.commit();
em.close();
emf.close();
}
}
```

PERSISTENCE CLASS CONFIGURATIONS

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entity.Automovel</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automovel?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1q2w3e4r"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Are you sure you have a running mySql server on your machine? The title of your question says "SQL server" which is a microsoft product.

Comment: Yes, i do! I'm running it...and my project is connected to the database

Comment: Then please edit the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: Should it be "Why I can't insert data into my SQL server through Java??" didn't got what you mean, i'm trying to insert information into my sql server

Comment: "SQL server" is a different database product than mySql.

Comment: oh got it, thanks man!